# Sequelize select not existing columns

Tags: mysql, node.js, select, sequelize.js

I do a simple create but sequelize always try to select a column 'userId' which neather exist or is used.

I do some database checks and if everything is OK, sequelize should just create it. But I get the message: "Unknown column 'uId' in 'field list'"

My Route:

```js
router.post('/rate', [verifyAuth, verifyNotBanned], function (req, res, next) {
    const productId = req.body.productId;
    const user_rating = parseInt(req.body.rating);

    // first look if user bought this product
    Purchase.findOne({where: {fk_buyer: req.decoded.id, fk_product: productId}}).then((purchase) => {
        if (!purchase) {
            let errNotBought = new Error();
            errNotBought.message = "you cant rate a product, which you not bought";
            errNotBought.status = 403;
            next(errNotBought);
        }
        // check if user already rated it
    }).then(() => Rating.findAndCountAll({where: {fk_user: req.decoded.id}}))
        .then((ratings) => {
            if (ratings.count > 0) {
                let errRated = new Error();
                errRated.message = "you already rated this product";
                errRated.status = 403;
                next(errRated);
            }
        })
        // save the rating
        .then(() => Rating.create({
            fk_user: req.decoded.id,
            fk_product: productId,
            rating: user_rating
        })).then((rate) => {
        res.send({status: true, data: rate})
    }).catch((err) => {
        next(err)
    });
});
```

My user_ratings Model:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const user_rating = sequelize.define('user_rating', {
        fk_user: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            onDelete: "SET NULL",
            onUpdate: "NO ACTION",
            references: {
                model: 'users',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        fk_product: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
            onUpdate: "NO ACTION",
            references: {
                model: 'products',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        rating: DataTypes.FLOAT
    }, {});
    user_rating.associate = function (models) {
        user_rating.belongsTo(models.user, {foreign_key: 'fk_user', unique: false});
        user_rating.belongsTo(models.product, {foreign_key: 'fk_product', unique: false});
    };
    return user_rating;
};
```

Is this a bug or what Im doing wrong?

The Migration file:

```js
 return queryInterface.createTable('user_ratings', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            fk_user: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                onDelete: "SET NULL",
                onUpdate: "NO ACTION",
                references: {
                    model: 'users',
                    key: 'id'
                }
            },
            fk_product: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                onDelete: "CASCADE",
                onUpdate: "NO ACTION",
                references: {
                    model: 'products',
                    key: 'id'
                }
            },
            rating: {
                type: Sequelize.FLOAT,
                allowNull: false
            },
            createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            }
        });
```

The generated Query:

> Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `fk_user`, `fk_product`, `rating`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `userId`, `productId` FROM `user_ratings` AS `user_rating` WHERE `user_rating`.`fk_user` = 1;

Comment: Your data model does not appear to feature a primary key. The foreign key entries can also be the primary key but they need to be defined as such.

Comment: the primary key is 'id' and is automaticly generated by sequelize

Comment: I added the migration file as well to my first post.

Comment: same issue here :(

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provided your sequelize version, can't assume exactly your problem, but according to sequelize version `5.21.7` your user_rating model is **misspelled**. I've had this same problem.

```
user_rating.associate = function (models) {
    user_rating.belongsTo(models.user, {foreign_key: 'fk_user', unique: false});
    user_rating.belongsTo(models.product, {foreign_key: 'fk_product', unique: false});
};
```

Your associate method should be with `foreignKey` not `foreign_key`. That's another tip for you to migrate to `typescript`

Here's your final associate function

```
user_rating.associate = function (models) {
    user_rating.belongsTo(models.user, {foreignKey: 'fk_user', unique: false});
    user_rating.belongsTo(models.product, {foreignKey: 'fk_product', unique: false});
};
```